# How to make a preview of an image uploaded in asyncfileupload within an iframe

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe, asyncfileupload

Code is working great. The preview after picking image using asyncfileupload appears. But once I place the page into an `iframe`, it doesn't work anymore.
I think the problem is that once it is place into the `iframe`, 
this script : **top.$get(\"" + ImagePreview.ClientID + "\")** can't really find my `ImagePreview`.

I tried using document.getElementById("<%= ImagePreview.ClientID %>") but no success.

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        Session["AsyncFileUpload1"] = AsyncFileUpload1;
        this.Session["AsyncFileUploadBytes"] = AsyncFileUpload1.FileBytes;
        Random random = new Random();
        int num = random.Next(10);
        string savePath = MapPath("~/Images/Temp/Preview" + num + ".jpg");
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "size", "top.$get(\"" + AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID + "\").innerHTML = 'Uploaded size: " + AsyncFileUpload1.FileBytes.Length.ToString() + "';", true);
        AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "image", "top.$get(\"" + ImagePreview.ClientID + "\").src = '../../../Images/Temp/Preview" + num + ".jpg'", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question says `ImagePreview.ClientID` but the code says `Image.ClientID`. Is one a typo?

Comment: Yup, I am sorry. I did change that to avoid confusion of image control to actual image. I edited my post, thank you.